# Where can we see the billing details or cost incurred details for each dataproc cluster in GCP console

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, billing, dataproc

I wanted to analyze the actual cost of each Dataproc cluster by having multiple machine types but I dont see any option to get the details of cost incurred of a single dataproc cluster in a GCP project
Where can we see the billing details or cost incurred details for each dataproc cluster in GCP console ?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/cost-management/use-labels-to-gain-visibility-into-gcp-resource-usage-and-spending

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks a Lot, will go through this document !

Answer (score 1):

[Dataproc on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) pricing is based on the size of Dataproc clusters and the duration of time that they run.

The size of a cluster is based on the aggregate number of virtual CPUs (vCPUs) across the entire cluster, including the master and worker nodes. The duration of a cluster is the length of time between cluster creation and cluster stopping or deletion.

The Dataproc pricing formula is: `$0.010 * # of vCPUs * hourly duration`.

Although the pricing formula is expressed as an hourly rate, Dataproc is billed by the second, and all Dataproc clusters are billed in one-second clock-time increments, subject to a 1-minute minimum billing. Usage is stated in fractional hours (for example, 30 minutes is expressed as 0.5 hours) in order to apply hourly pricing to second-by-second use.

The [Dataproc on GKE](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dpgke/dataproc-gke-overview) pricing formula, `$0.010 * # of vCPUs * hourly duration`, is the same as the Dataproc on Compute Engine pricing formula, and is applied to the aggregate number of virtual CPUs running in VMs instances in [Dataproc-created node pools](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/dpgke/dataproc-gke-nodepools) in the cluster.
The duration of a virtual machine instance is the length of time from its creation to its deletion.

As with Dataproc on Compute Engine, Dataproc on GKE is billed by the second, subject to a 1-minute minimum billing per virtual machine instance. Other Google Cloud charges are applied in addition to Dataproc charges.

Dataproc-created node pools continue to exist after deletion of the Dataproc cluster since they may be shared by multiple clusters. If you delete the node pools or scale node pools down to zero instances, continued Dataproc charges will not be incurred. Any remaining node pool VMs will continue to incur charges until you delete them.

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/pricing).